# External Hard Drive Wont Reformat or Read in PC

Tags: external-hard-drive

History: My Dish DVR failed and I tried to use my external hard drive to recover movies from my DVR. I attached it to the DVR with the USB. It lit up as it was trying to function but It wouldnt reformat in the DVR because it didnt have its own power supply. So then I bought a used External Hard Drive that did have its own power suplply and that did work and I was able to recover the movies and transfer them to the new DVR.

So then when I went to use either one of my external hard drives on my PC again neither one would show up on my computer and I cant access them, I do see them in the Device Manager under disk drives when they are attached but they will not load or open.

When I Open Computer Management > Storage > Disk Management I can see my C: drive with everything working and healthy. But in the box under that I believe Im looking at the External Hard Drive and it also says healthy but I cant reformat it , the only option when I right click it is "delete volume" .. Is this a partition issue ?

What happened when I plugged these two external hard drives to my DVR.. I know the one that worked is reformatted but now it doesn't read in my PC either.. Can this be fixed.. without ruining my PC.?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the HDD was formatted with a file system that Windows doesn't recognize. If there's no data on this drive that you need then just delete the volume and create a new one. There's no risk of damaging your PC or your existing volumes on other drives.